# In asyncore how can i send data to all or some of the clients?

Tags: python, sockets, asyncore

I'm building a little MMORPG and im trying to use asyncore rather then threading.

1) How would i send data to certain clients, because in threading a saved each clients socket and current in a dictionary a with its unique id as a key. So how could i subjective send data to all the clients.

Thankyou, please say if i didnt give enough information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it great that you want to move to asynchronous programming instead of threading, since it is so much reliable and easier to debug.

However, `asyncore` is a bad library to do so. I don't advise you use it at all, since it requires a significant rewrite to do simple things like read standard io.

I suggest you move to [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) - it is a great asynchronous framework, well tested and developed, with good api documentation and good community support.

Regardless of your decision on which library to use, I find this [series of blog posts by Dave Peticolas](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327) to be a great source of beginner information on asynchronous programming. Please read it.

There are some games under development using twisted. One example is [Minions of Mirth](http://www.minionsofmirth.com/) - I never played it but it seems cool.

There's also [divmod's imaginary](http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodImaginary) - it's *a simulationist's take on the realm of role playing, interactive fiction, and multiplayer dungeons. It incorporates gameplay features from each area while attempting to provide a richer environment than is generally available from existing systems.*

Hope I helped.